# Play a Youtube video from an iframe on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, iframe, video, youtube, windows-phone

In a Windows Phone 8 application I'm currently developing (C#), I'm trying to play a Youtube video.

In my page, I have a `webBrowser` component, and I display some static HTML with the function `NavigateToString()`.

When I execute my app, in my `webBrowser` component, I can see the Youtube player with the first image of the video I'm trying to play.

If I tap the "play button", I can see a loader on the player, then I have a redirection on the video full screen app and have the following **error message : "Sorry, we can't play this file on your phone"**.

If with the Internet Explorer app I navigate on Youtube website and try to play a video, everything works fine.

I really hope that somebody will be able to help me :)

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot play Youtube videos in your application. IE simply redirects you to a built-in player which you cannot really access.

But you could always download the video locally and play it. This might help: [MyToolkit](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube&referringTitle=Documentation).

Comment: Hi !
Thank you for your answer. As a workaround, I would like to detect when the user tap on the Youtube video preview to redirect him directly on the Youtube webpage through the WebBrowserTask. Do you know how to catch when the user tap on the Youtube video preview ?

Answer (score 0):

**Thats wrong!**

There is an opportunity to integrate YouTube videos in an WP 8.0 and WP 8.1 application.

I'm using de Windows Phone App Studio (http://appstudio.windows.com/) to build an app which I extend via Visual Studio after generating an downloadable code package.

And there you can add an YouTube channel, playlist or specific video by searching for it.

If you've implementet the feature you can click to open the Video in your application in fullscren.
If you're creating an WP 8.1 app you can also play the video without full-screen mode.

There is also a tutorial to integrate YouTube Videos in your App: http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.de/2013/07/embed-youtube-videos-into-your-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

after playing a little bit i made it work on WP8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html,charset=yourEncoding">
<title>title here </title>
</head>
<body >
 <iframe width="550" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/videoId" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>   
</body>
</html>
```

seems like the reason it didn't work was that "text/html" and "charset=yourEncoding" was separated with a ";" instead of a ","